# Android in-app billing - available in Canada?

Tags: android, android-pay

Every time I try to enable it in the play store, nothing happens and the page just reloads. I have tried adding a merchant account, but only UK and US were options. I'm pretty sure I read that Canada can have in-app billing, so what can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Canada can certainly have in-app billing...I am Canadian and some of my releases have IAP enabled...can you give more information about the problem?

Comment: Basically when I click "Set up a Merchant Account" in the Google Play Store settings of the app, nothing happens. Page just reloads or I'm dumped back to the home page.

Comment: Try this link https://checkout.google.com/sell/

Answer (score 0):

Your Google Account is probably already linked to UK/US country.

You need to create a new account if you want a Canadian account.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Hartok for the cause of the problem.  As for it being available in Canada, It certainly is!